# QtCreator cross-compiler Yocto: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets webkit

Tags: qt, webkit, qt5, qt-creator, yocto

I have compiled and running a Yocto Poky `fsl-image-multimedia-full` image and the `browser` and `fancybrowser` webkit examples work fine (iMX6 SABRE DL for SDP board).

In addition, `meta-toolchain-qt` has been built and installed fine.

I was trying to build a simple `QWebView` example using QtCreator configured to cross-compiler and deploy into the device but no compile and show the next error:

**`Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit`**

Output detail:

`14:36:38: Running steps for project QtWebViewExample...
14:36:38: Starting: "/home/user/workspace/Yocto_k4/fsl-release-bsp/build-multimedia/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/nativesdk-qtbase/5.5.1+gitAUTOINC+5afc431323-r0/build/bin/qmake" /home/jdavid/workspace/qtcreator/QtWebViewExample/QtWebViewExample.pro -r -spec linux-oe-g++
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: gui webkitwidgets
14:36:38: The process "/home/jdavid/workspace/Yocto_k4/fsl-release-bsp/build-multimedia/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/nativesdk-qtbase/5.5.1+gitAUTOINC+5afc431323-r0/build/bin/qmake" exited with code 3.
Error while building/deploying project QtWebViewExample (kit: SABRE)
When executing step "qmake"
14:36:38: Elapsed time: 00:00.`

The same process and QtCreator kit configuration **work fine with non-webkit applications**. The errors only appears when include the `webkit` o `webkitwidgets` dependency.

I'm trying to solve it with a lot of questions found in stackoverflow, NXP community, etc. but any solve the problem. Some examples:

- Using `QT += webkitwidgets` and `QT += webkit` alternatives.
- Installing `sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev`.
- Adding the `INCLUDEPATH` set to qt5 lib directory.

Any solution works for me, QtCreator no detect the `webkitwidgets` library.

More info:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Qt 5.5.1
- yocto poky

Does anyone have any other ideas because QtCreator no detect the `webkitwidgets` library?

Thanks,

Comment: webkit is deprecated, use webengine

Answer (score 0):

The `webkitwidgets` library has been abandoned since Qt5.6 (and not Qt5 sorry). You should use the `webenginewidgets` library (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html) and [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-index.html)).

Comment: Since **Qt 5.6**, not since Qt 5.